# Can't deactivate conda

Tags: python, conda

I have deactivated conda many times before, but suddenly have an error that is keeping me from doing much of anything:

```
$ conda deactivate
Error processing line 1 of /home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib-3.0.3-py3.7-nspkg.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site.py", line 168, in addpackage
      exec(line)
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 580, in module_from_spec
  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'

Remainder of file ignored
```

What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: Do other conda commands, for example, `conda env list` work?